# Why is file_put_contents() giving my files crazy names?

Tags: php, file

Trying to create backups using PHP.

```
$filename = getcwd() . "/backup/" . $slug . date("Y-m-d-h:i:sa") . ".inc";
echo $filename;
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Expected output filenames:

```
myfile2014-02-13-4:53:04pm.inc
myfile2014-02-13-4:54:29pm.inc
```

Actual output filenames:

```
T6L3PF~C.INC
TAT6YB~L.INC
```

Also, it is taking a really long time to create the file. This is the really strange thing: I'm also creating another file in the same script--except not in the backup directory.

```
$filename = getcwd() . "/" . $slug . ".html";
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

It always works perfectly and always is created instantly, no delay.

```
myfile.html
```

The backup file isn't created for over a minute, even though it precedes the `.html` part of the script!

Comment: Sounds like a Windows problem to me.

Comment: I'm using OSX, not sure what the server is, I assumed it was LAMP.

Comment: What are you making the backup onto?

Comment: `phpinfo()` reports this for System: `Linux webhosting-www[redacted].el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 10:48:38 EDT 2013 x86_641`

Comment: To clarify, in case I misunderstood your question: the backup is on the server with the PHP script, in a folder `/backup`. Not anything tricky.

Comment: How are you viewing the files?

Comment: I mount the drive in OSX. You know: `smb://my/path`

Comment: Try turning on debugging with `display_errors` and `error_reporting` to see if any errors are being thrown. Also, try to `var_dump` the result of `file_put_contents()` to see if the numbers of bytes at least match the expected or if `false` is being returned. You could also use `$filename = "./backup/". $slug [...]` to use relative path instead of absolute.

Comment: @mathielo, I don't have that kind of access to the server, so unfortunately no configuring PHP. I tried `$filename = "./backup/" . $pageSlug . date("Y-m-d-h:i:sa") . ".inc";` but it doesn't work at all. (?)

Comment: @brentonstrine what about the `var_dump` of `file_put_contents()`? Is it returning `FALSE` or the bytes of the written file? Have you tried different approaches such as [`fopen(); fwrite(); fclose();`](http://br2.php.net/function.file-put-contents#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-seealso) instead?

Comment: @mathielo, sorry, I had to look up how to use `var_dump`. This code `echo var_dump(file_put_contents($filename, $content));` outputs `bool(false)`.

Comment: @brentonstrine As [PHP's Documentation](http://br2.php.net/function.file-put-contents#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-returnvalues) states: "This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.". Therefore, your function is not working properly. If the `.html` file works, maybe it could be a problem related to system file extensions. Try changing `.INC` to `.txt` just for a quick test. Hint: `var_dump()` automatically echoes, so no need for `echo var_dump()` ;)

Comment: Very confusing, because it does create the file (with correct content), it just takes a few minutes. Changing to `.txt` makes no difference. Also, I've been able to create `.inc` files by using a simpler filename (`"/backup/test.inc").

Comment: @mathielo Ok, crap, I introduced a syntax error. The actual output is `int(901)`.

Comment: @brentonstrine If `.INC` extension is not the problem as you created `test.inc`, then I'm 99% sure the problem lies on the chosen file name. Try switching `:` of `date("Y-m-d-h:i:sa")` to `-` (or whatever), like so: `date("Y-m-d-h-i-sa")`. You're probably generating a file system conflict using `:` in your file name as this symbol is often used to determine protocols or ports.

Comment: @mathielo ah, didn't see this till after I posted an 'answer'. Please submit this as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @brentonstrine nah, I'm glad it worked out for you. Even though I tried to help, you found the solution by yourself and learned something new :) Keep on coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was here:

```
date("Y-m-d-h:i:sa")
```

which should produce:

```
2014-02-13-4:53:04pm
```

but apparently the `:` was messing everything up. Changed it to `date("Y-m-d-h.i.sa")`, everything working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

> `smb://my/path`

Well there you go. Since ":" is not a valid filepath character in Windows, Samba gives a fake filename instead of the one you expect. Mount over SSH instead.

Comment: Does the way I mount it to view it really make a difference? The script is run on a Linux server (AFAICT) and writes the file to a directory on the same server.

Comment: Yes, it does. Samba assumes that the client will be a Windows machine, and gives it Windows-friendly filenames.

Comment: But if I unmount the drive and then try to view the file in the browser, it still is the same, no Samba involved. Or am I misunderstanding how Samba works? Does Samba control all file creation on the LAMP server?

Comment: How are you viewing the file in the browser?

Comment: With a URL. Also, if `:` was the problem, then my `.html` file wouldn't be written correctly, but it is.

Comment: The ":" is a problem when viewing the filename via Windows-friendly methods. The file is written to the filesystem normally.

Comment: If it was written to the filesystem normally, wouldn't a browser be able to retrieve it normally?

Comment: It depends on what scheme you're using to view it with.